# Restrict write access of executable

Tags: bash, filesystems, users, group

I'm creating a file system manager that has extensions for automatic creation of projects, ...
The filesystem executable should only be able to edit or remove files in `/home/USER/00_Files`

I created a user and group with `sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --group filesystem`.

Afterwards i changed the home folder in `/etc/passwd` to `filesystem:x:131:140::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin`. (no idea if this was a good idea)

My current understanding is that should run the filesystem executable as the user I created and have the group filesystem own all the files in `00_Files`.

Other programs (like my IDE) (or me in the terminal) will be editing, adding and removing files in `00_Files`.

Now for the questions:

How do I run an executable as the user `filesystem`?

How do I automaticly let the group `filesystem` own all files in `00_Files`?

Any other filepermisions I should set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## run an executable as the user `filesystem`

```
# execute as root
chown filesystem /path/to/executable
chmod u+s /path/to/executable
# execute as any user
/path/to/executable
```

It makes more sense to run this with SGID than SUID, though (then the user `filesystem` cannot modify this executable):

```
# execute as root
chown root:filesystem /path/to/executable
chmod u-s,g+s /path/to/executable
# execute as any user
/path/to/executable
```

In both cases you may have to make `/home/USER` searchable (`x` permission) for the group `filesystem` (by making it the group of that directory or with ACLs).

## let a group own all new files

Make it the group of all existing files and directories

```
chgrp -R /home/USER/00_Files
```

Set the SGID bit for all directories:

```
find /home/USER/00_Files -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

## other file permissions to be set

Make all existing files and directories writable by the group:

```
chmod -R g+w /home/USER/00_Files
```

Give write permission to group for all future files and directories:

```
find /home/USER/00_Files -type d -exec setfacl -m d:g::rwx {} \;
```

## for this to be safe

For this to be safe there must not be any files or directories with write permission for the user/group `filesystem` outside this directory tree.

A completely different approach would be to run the executable in its own mount namespace /chroot which only contains the target directory tree. This should be simple if the executable is statically linked. I am not sure whether `root` privilege is required for creating a namespace, though.